# WebView does not load

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, wkwebview

I just started developing with swift, so I am sorry if the question is basic/stupid.

I have the following setup, just a test

```
import WebKit
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, WKNavigationDelegate {

var webView: WKWebView!

override func loadView() {

    webView = WKWebView()
    webView.navigationDelegate = self
    view = webView
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let url = URL(string: "https://hackingswift.com")!
    webView.load(URLRequest(url:url))
    webView.allowsBackForwardNavigationGestures = true

}

}
```

Unfortunately the browser doesn't load. The simulator only shows an empty navigation bar.
Suggestions? I am following a tutorial on hackingswift, so it's supposed to work.

Answer (score 0):

You have to add webView as a subview or make an IBOutlet using Interface builder.

Try this:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, WKNavigationDelegate {

    var webView: WKWebView?

   func loadView() {            
        webView = WKWebView()
        webView?.navigationDelegate = self
        self.view.addSubview(webView!)
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.loadView()
        let url = URL(string: "https://hackingswift.com")!
        webView?.load(URLRequest(url:url))
        webView?.allowsBackForwardNavigationGestures = true
    }

}
```

If you want it a bit more simple (without nullable variable), for example:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, WKNavigationDelegate {

    var webView = WKWebView()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        webView.navigationDelegate = self
        self.view.addSubview(webView)
        webView?.allowsBackForwardNavigationGestures = true
        self.loadUrl("https://hackingswift.com")
    }

    func loadUrl(_ url: String) {            
        if let url = URL(string: url) {
            webView.load(URLRequest(url:url))
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It seems like neither works, unfortunately. I embedded it in a navigation controller, could that be the issue?

Comment: EDIT: it looks like some websites to load, while others do not, even if they are secure. If I put apple.com in the example, it loads, but a few others do not

Answer (score 0):

> EDIT: it looks like some websites to load, while others do not, even if they are secure. If I put apple.com in the example, it loads, but a few others do not

Your url should be started with **http** or **https** for the webView to load.

Another possible reason is that your url containing an invalid certificate. Add the delegate function below into your code. You have to let WKWebView to bypass the certificate checking. However, this code is never recommended to go into production. You should be careful about what website your webView should and will load.

```
func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didReceive challenge: URLAuthenticationChallenge, completionHandler: @escaping (URLSession.AuthChallengeDisposition, URLCredential?) -> Void) {
    let cred = URLCredential(trust: challenge.protectionSpace.serverTrust!)
    completionHandler(.useCredential, cred)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is this line:

```
let url = URL(string: "https://hackingswift.com")!
```

There is no such URL on the Internet, so you're not actually going to see anything. (You won't see anything if you paste that URL into *any* browser.)

So change that line to this:

```
let url = URL(string: "https://www.hackingwithswift.com")!
```

Now run the app, and presto, you'll see the web site:

[image]